# dart/flutter update keys of map

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to update the keys of a map.
I sorted the map by date, but now the keys are not in numerical order

original Map:

```
Map<dynamic, dynamic> myMap = {
    0: {"id": 754, "name": "luke", "date": 1665537500000},
    1: {"id": 436, "name": "obi", "date": 1665532400000},
    2: {"id": 866, "name": "vader", "date": 1665532500000},
  };

myMapSorted = SplayTreeMap.from(myMap, (a, b) => myMap[a]['time'].compareTo(myMap[b]['time']));
print(myMapSorted);
```

sorted Map (with keys in not numerical order):

```
{
    1: {"id": 436, "name": "obi", "date":  1665532400000},
    2: {"id": 866, "name": "vader", "date": 1665532500000},
    0: {"id": 754, "name": "luke", "date": 1665537500000}, 
  };
```

is there a way to update the keys?

Comment: This [issue](https://www.educative.io/answers/how-to-create-a-sorted-map-by-value-in-dart) can be of help.

Comment: If your goal is to have `myMap[0]` correspond to the oldest item, and if your `Map`'s keys are consecutive integers starting from 0, why are use a `Map` at all?  Use a `List`.

Comment: @jamesdlin I need "id" and "name" corresponding to the oldest date as well

Comment: @Bernhard My point is that you don't need the `Map` key and can just use a `List` of your `Map` values.  A `Map` with consecutive integer keys in order starting from 0 should be a `List` instead.  It's simpler and more efficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you find yourself using a `Map` with integer keys that are contiguous and where you don't care about insertion order, you should step back and ask yourself if you should be using a `List` instead, especially if your keys also start from 0.  Using a `List` is simpler and more efficient.

It sounds like that applies to your situation.  Instead of:

> ```dart
> Map<dynamic, dynamic> myMap = {
>     0: {"id": 754, "name": "luke", "date": 1665537500000},
>     1: {"id": 436, "name": "obi", "date": 1665532400000},
>     2: {"id": 866, "name": "vader", "date": 1665532500000},
>   };
> ```

use:

```dart
var myMap = <dynamic>[
    {"id": 754, "name": "luke", "date": 1665537500000},
    {"id": 436, "name": "obi", "date": 1665532400000},
    {"id": 866, "name": "vader", "date": 1665532500000},
];
```

and then you can sort it directly with:

```dart
myMap.sort((a, b) => a['date'].compareTo(b['date']));
```

to obtain:

```
[
  {'id': 436, 'name': 'obi', 'date': 1665532400000},
  {'id': 866, 'name': 'vader', 'date': 1665532500000},
  {'id': 754, 'name': 'luke', 'date': 1665537500000},
]
```

And now you don't need to worry about updating any `Map` keys since they are implicitly the indices of the `List` elements.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by [Ουιλιαμ Αρκευα](https://stackoverflow.com/users/955594/%ce%9f%cf%85%ce%b9%ce%bb%ce%b9%ce%b1%ce%bc-%ce%91%cf%81%ce%ba%ce%b5%cf%85%ce%b1), the second method of [article](https://www.educative.io/answers/how-to-create-a-sorted-map-by-value-in-dart) solves your issue of sorting by keys.

```
var sortMapByKey = Map.fromEntries(
    myMap.entries.toList()
    ..sort((e1, e2) => e1.key.compareTo(e2.key)));
    
  print("***Sorted Map by key***");
  print(sortMapByKey);
```

Comment: then I have the old map, what sense does that make? I want the new map but with 0,1,2 instead of 1,2,0 as keys